# How do I filter XML nodes and its child nodes in a XML document?

Tags: c#, xml

So I have a XML document in which I get as a HttpWebResponse from an API I'm working with. However, the document in which I get is about 166 thousand rows long and includes a lot of unnecessary data in which I don't need. I've read the API documentation and it doesn't seem that there is a filtering attribute in which suits my needs. So I figured that I would filter it programmatically but I haven't been able to succeed on that part. So the XML document looks a bit like this:

```
<sensortree>
        <nodes>
            <group id="">
                <name></name>
                <id></id>
                <url></url>
                <tags></tags>
                <priority></priority>
                <fixed></fixed>
                <hascomment></hascomment>
                <status_raw></status_raw>
                <active></active>
                <probenode id="">
                    <name></name>
                    <id></id>
                    <url></url>
                    <tags></tags>
                    <priority></priority>
                    <fixed></fixed>
                    <hascomment></hascomment>
                    <status_raw></status_raw>
                    <active></active>
                    <group id="">
                        <name></name>
                        <id></id>
                        <url></url>
                        <tags></tags>
                        <priority></priority>
                        <fixed></fixed>
                        <hascomment></hascomment>
                        <status_raw></status_raw>
                        <active></active>
                        <group id="">
                            <name></name>
                            <id></id>
                            <url></url>
                            <tags></tags>
                            <priority></priority>
                            <fixed></fixed>
                            <hascomment></hascomment>
                            <status_raw></status_raw>
                            <active></active>
                            <group id="">
                                <name></name>
                                <id></id>
                                <url></url>
                                <tags></tags>
                                <priority></priority>
                                <fixed></fixed>
                                <hascomment></hascomment>
                                <status_raw></status_raw>
                                <active></active>
                                <device id="">
                                    <summary></summary>
                                    <name></name>
                                    <deviceicon></deviceicon>
                                    <id></id>
                                    <url></url>
                                    <tags></tags>
                                    <priority></priority>
                                    <fixed></fixed>
                                    <hascomment></hascomment>
                                    <host></host>
                                    <status_raw></status_raw>
                                    <active></active>
                                    <sensor id="">
                                        <name></name>
                                        <id></id>
                                        <url></url>
                                        <tags></tags>
                                        <priority></priority>
                                        <fixed></fixed>
                                        <hascomment></hascomment>
                                        <sensortype></sensortype>
                                        <sensorkind></sensorkind>
                                        <interval></interval>
                                        <status_raw></status_raw>
                                        <status></status>
                                        <datamode></datamode>
                                        <lastvalue></lastvalue>
                                        <lastvalue_raw></lastvalue_raw>
                                        <statusmessage></statusmessage>
                                        <active></active>
                                    </sensor>
                                </device>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </probenode>
            </group>
        </nodes>
</sensortree>
```

Now you might notice that all elements are empty, that is because I have deleted all inner texts of the elements as I cannot share that information with the public, although I asure you that all elements have inner texts in reality. Now each device also have multiple sensors but they all look the same so I only included one. All the group elements also have a different structure of child nodes so each group is not like the other. Now I only need the elements "nodes", "group", "probenode", "device", "sensor", "name" and "id". The rest of the elements needs to be deleted from the document while I still keep the hierarchical structure of the document. So in short what I want to do is loop through all the nodes and each nodes child nodes, see if the element is an element I want to keep and delete it if it isn't. Another twist is that I don't know if XPath is an option because the structure is not the same everywhere. Things I have tried are the following.

```
//Method 1 - It doesn't delete the nodes that are not specified, I think it's because it doesn't check the childnodes because it does delete other nodes.
foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc)
            {
                if (node.Name == "group" || node.Name == "probenode" ||     node.Name == "device" || node.Name == "sensor")
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                }
            }

//Method 2 - Not sure how to delete a node from a XmlReader instance 
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xDoc.WriteTo(xw);
            String xmlString = sw.ToString();

            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlString));
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (rdr.LocalName == "group" || rdr.LocalName == "probenode" || rdr.LocalName == "device" || rdr.LocalName == "sensor"
                    || rdr.LocalName == "name" || rdr.LocalName == "lastvalue" || rdr.LocalName == "status")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Now this is what I want my xml document to look like after it's formatted:

```
<sensortree>
        <nodes>
            <group id="">
                <name></name>
                <id></id>
                    <probenode id="">
                    <name></name>
                    <id></id>
                    <group id="">
                        <name></name>
                        <id></id>
                            <name></name>
                            <id></id>
                            <group id="">
                                <name></name>
                                <id></id>
                                <device id="">
                                    <name></name>
                                    <id></id>
                                    <sensor id="">
                                        <name></name>
                                        <id></id>
                                    </sensor>
                                </device>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </probenode>
            </group>
        </nodes>
</sensortree>
```

Comment: I know this may not answer your question but try using `XDocument` when working with xml in C# it's a far more enjoyable experience https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Xml.Linq`:

```cs
// first get System.Xml.Linq.XDocument from XmlDocument
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDocument.OuterXml);

// remove elements from xDoc that do not match one of your expected tags
var tags = new string[] { "group", "sensor", ... }
xDoc.Root.Descendants().Where(d => !tags.Contains(d.Name.LocalName)).Remove();
```

Comment: better solution than the accepted one; shorter, simpler and usex XDocument instead of XmlDocument...

Comment: Yes I agree and therefore I switched the accepted method to this one. Both methods does the same job and gives the same result but this one is much simpler. Thank you Udo for your help!

Comment: @rasqall Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

See if following recursive algorithm works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument oldDoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement oldNodes = oldDoc.Descendants("nodes").FirstOrDefault();

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><sensortree><nodes></nodes></sensortree>";

            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement newNodes = newDoc.Descendants("nodes").FirstOrDefault();

            GetTreeRecursively(oldNodes, newNodes);

        }
        static void GetTreeRecursively(XElement oldElement, XElement newElement)
        {
            string[] findTags = { "group", "probenode", "device", "sensor" };

            List<XElement> oldChildren = oldElement.Elements().Where(x => findTags.Contains(x.Name.LocalName)).ToList();

            foreach (XElement oldChild in oldChildren)
            {
                XElement newChild = new XElement(oldChild.Name.LocalName, new XAttribute("id", (string)oldChild.Attribute("id")));
                newChild.Add(oldChild.Element("name"));
                newChild.Add(oldChild.Element("id"));
                newElement.Add(newChild);
                GetTreeRecursively(oldChild, newChild);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are an amazing person. Flawless algorithm!

Comment: although this is working, Udo's solution is better for sake of clarity and simplicity

Comment: I agree, but I think you did an amazing job regardless and thank you so much for your help!